# Assuming a normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The height of students is distributed with an average of $186.7\; cm$ and an SD of $5.6\;cm$. 200 samples of 50 students (i.e. 200 groups of 50 students) were taken from the population, and the average of each group of 50 was computed.

What is the average number of samples in which the average height of students is between $184.2\; cm$ and $187.7\;cm?$

I'm unsure how to go about solving this question - without assuming a normal distribution (and thus using Z-scores). Is there another way to do it? What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observe two questions.  Should you be willing to use the normal distribution in general and should you be willing to use the normal distribution to describe the distribution of sample means.

Answering the second question first: You are looking at the distribution of sample means, to which the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) has some chance of applying.  You are given that the mean and standard deviation of the distribution of student heights is finite, so the (classical or Lindeberg-Levy, using the terms on the cited page) central limit theorem applies and the distribution of sample means is normal.

Answering the first question:  The normal distribution is the [maximum entropy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Specified_variance:_the_normal_distribution) given only a central parameter (mean) and dispersion (standard deviation or variance).  From that page:

> According to the principle of maximum entropy, if nothing is known about a distribution except that it belongs to a certain class (usually defined in terms of specified properties or measures), then the distribution with the largest entropy should be chosen as the least-informative default. The motivation is twofold: first, maximizing entropy minimizes the amount of prior information built into the distribution; second, many physical systems tend to move towards maximal entropy configurations over time."

In short, since you *only* know the mean and standard deviation, the most conservative assumption, the choice that assumes the least beyond those two parameters of the distribution, is the normal distribution.  (This ignores a small technicality.  The normal distribution has support on $(-\infty, \infty)$.  In reality student heights cannot be negative.  We should consider the maximum entropy distribution restricted to nonnegative support.  However, zero is more than thirty given standard deviations from the given mean, so until the population of students is greater than or comparable to $10^{244}$, or **vastly** more students than [atoms in the observable universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_%E2%80%93_number_of_atoms), this detail is negligible.)

Answer (score 0):

The average $Y$ of each group of 50 elements has an asymptotic Gaussian distribution $N(186.7;\frac{5.6^2}{50})$

So simply calculate the probabilty that in each group

$\mathbb{P}[184.2 \leq Y \leq 187.7]=\Phi(\frac{187.7-186.7}{5.6}\sqrt{50})-\Phi(\frac{184.2-186.7}{5.6}\sqrt{50})\approx 0.896$

Now set $\approx 0.896=0.9=p$ and observe that the requested rv is a binomial $Bin(200; 0.9)$

So the average number you are looking for is simply $np=200\times0.9=180$ (approximate)